# CSS keep items in the center with margin bottom

Tags: html, css

I need to create a tags section. The container should be with fixed padding, and when the tags wrap to the next line, it should be with spacing from the top line.

The problem is that when it wraps to the next line, it's not aligned to center anymore. How can I keep the spacing between lines and the fixed padding in the container?

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.align-center {
  align-items: center;
}

.wrap {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

section {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  min-height: 40px;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
}

.item {
  background-color: hotpink;
  padding: 0.3em;
  margin-right: 0.4em;
  margin-bottom: 0.3em;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<section class="flex align-center wrap">

  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to defined the same *top & bottom* `padding` for the `.flex` *container*, which will keep the `.item`s *vertically centered* all the time, then just adjust the *child's* `margin` to achieve an *equal spacing* between them:

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  min-height: 40px;
  width: 400px;
  padding: .5em .2em;
  animation: width 4s linear infinite alternate;
}

.item {
  background-color: hotpink;
  padding: .3em;
  margin: .2em;
}

@keyframes width {to {width: 100px}}
```

```html
<section class="flex">
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
</section>
```

Comment: And what if I need a smaller margin for the items?

Comment: Np, just change the value to whatever you want, I just thought that you want to have the same spacing all-around.

Comment: I want the container to be with 0.5em padding and the space between lines 0.2em. How can I do it with your solution?

Comment: Modified to your needs.

Comment: Wrote an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Add `margin-top: 0.3em` to child div

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.align-center {
  align-items: center;
}

.wrap {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

section {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  min-height: 40px;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
}

.item {
  background-color: hotpink;
  padding: 0.3em;
  margin-right: 0.4em;
  margin-bottom: 0.3em;
  margin-top: 0.3em;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<section class="flex align-center wrap">

  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>

</section>
```

Comment: I want them to align on the y-axis, not the x-axis.

Comment: That wasn't clear from your question. And if you are giving margin to child element from bottom only then how can you expect them to have equal spaces around y axis.

Comment: I have updated the snippet by assuming that you need equal space from top and bottom between tags and parent.

Comment: And what if I need a smaller margin for the items?

Comment: In any case better way to do styling would be giving top and bottom padding to parent for spacing between tags and parent, and give top and bottom margin to child to give spacing between tags.